# Swift: Why does adding an image subview take so long?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a simple Table View Application in Swift. I am trying to pass an image to my local node server, and have the server send back this received image, having altered it in no way, and display it on the iPhone screen. Embedded in each cell is a button that initiates this post/response handling. The button calls the following function:

```
func uploadImage() {
    /* Encode UIImage to be passed to server */
    let image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    var params = ["username":"myUsername", "image": base64String ] as Dictionary

    /* Set up request */
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/postRequestHere")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")    

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        if(err) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            /* Server returns JSON as follows: {"success":imageData} */
            var success = json["success"] as NSString
            let successData = NSData(base64EncodedString: success, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromMask(0))

            /* Begin Reference A */
            let returnImage = UIImage(data: successData)
            let newImageView = UIImageView(image: returnImage)
            newImageView.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(newImageView)
            /* End Reference A */
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The image I get back is correct, and everything works as it should. However, it takes about 20 seconds to show the image (from Reference A). I've even used a local image in reference A, using no data returned from the server, and this still takes the same time. If I put reference A outside of the task, using a local image, this shows instantly.

I test by running in the simulator.

Comment: If you print something within the dataTaskWithRequest block, does it also take 20 seconds to show up in the log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding `newImageView` on `secondary thread`.All UI must be updated on `main thread`.So call `addSubview` on main thread.Replace your code with this

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update UI on the main thread
        let newImageView = UIImageView(image: returnImage)
        newImageView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(newImageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do believe that it should be "dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in" instead of "dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{" in Swift

Answer (score 0):

You need to run UIImage on **main thread** to make it fast.

I believe your image is part of your GUI cause you need it fast! and so it should be on **main** thread.

Try this :

```
          DispatchQueue.main.sync {
          image = UIImage(data: imageData)
          let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
          imageView.frame = self.view.frame
          self.view.addSubview(imageView)
          self.view.bringSubview(toFront: imageView)
        }
```